# calendar control

Tags: calendar

i wanna load calendar when i click the textbox (in asp.net C#).. how can i implement that..?

can anyone tell me the idea to do that..?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use ASP.NET controls then I would recommend the Ajax Control Tool kit:

[Calendar Extender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)

otherwise use any of these javascript based client side tools:

Jquery UI [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) or any of these [Calendars](http://www.bigwebmaster.com/JavaScript/Scripts_and_Programs/Calendars/)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [Ex-“Coolest” DHTML Calendar](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/old/) for a few years now in an asp.net project, without problems.

If I would upgrade I pick the [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), because jQuery is already used in the project. But the new [coolest DHTML Calendar](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/) is a nice one also.

All you need with all these calendars is an asp:textbox. On the client side you attach the calendar and when the form get's posted you have to parse the date in code-behind.
If you put this in a control you can reuse the calendar everywhere in your project.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `Calendar control` and `PopupControl Extender` comes with Ajax Control toolkit.

check [this link](http://walikata.blogspot.com/2012/07/calendar-control-date-disable.html). maybe it helps.